# C++ equivalence to self.object(python)

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ but have working with python for a while now.. and I can't figure this out...
I've tried using "this" pointer but I get an error so I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

This is what I'm trying to achieve :

I have a date and a person class and I have to add a class method to check if the person would be and adult or a child

this is my method so far :

```
bool isAdult()
{
    util::Date today = util::Date();

    int age = today.getYear()- this.getYear();

    if (today.getMonth() < this.getMonth() || (today.getMonth() == this.getMonth() && today.getDay() < this.getDay()))
    {
        age = age -1;
    }

    if (age >= 18)
    {return true;}
    else{return false;}


}
```

How come I am able to do something like this :

```
ostringstream os;
os << getDay() << " \n";
os << getMonth() << " \n";
os << getYear();
```

But I cant do this :

```
long year = getYear();
```

Comment: What is the error? That will help everyone nail the problem in a better way

Comment: Show the code please so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I made an assumption about what you're getting at here, but I agree with the above comments: you should show what you're trying to do by showing some code.

Comment: I'm trying to call getYear,getMonth and getDay to compare them with today's date. I'm just wondering how I would do self.getDay in c++

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++, `this` is a pointer type, so you probably need to dereference it to invoke members.

There are two ways to dereference a pointer for invoking members:

```
// Using the * operator to get the actual instance
auto result = (*this).do_something();

// Using the -> operator to dereference and get/invoke member simultaneously
auto result = this->do_something();
```

Comment: Or you can just omit `this` altogether.

Comment: True, but I find it more readable (and appreciate the fact that it's basically required in Python).

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. I find it too verbose and less readable.

Comment: I'm trying this with my getYear method and I'm getting an error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union

Comment: Did you try the `->` operator?

Comment: Yes same thing happens.

Comment: Found my error and I feel bad... bool Date::isAdult() instead of bool isAdult()